# Odoo. TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, orm, odoo, typeerror, odoo-8

I have problrem with my code.

```
class SiteTrip(models.Model):
    _name = 'vips_vc.site_trip'

    name = fields.Char()
    session_ids = fields.One2many('vips_vc.session', 'site_trip_id', string='Session ID', index=True)
    url_prevouse_ids = fields.Many2one('vips_vc.url_list', string='Prevouse URL', index=True)
    url_current_ids  = fields.Many2one('vips_vc.url_list', string='Current URL',  index=True)

class URLList(models.Model):
    _name = 'vips_vc.url_list'

    name = fields.Char(string="URL", required=True)
    url_parametes = fields.Char(string="URL parameters") 

    target_session_id = fields.One2many('vips_vc.session', 'target_url_ids', string='Target URL')

    site_trip_prevouse_id = fields.One2many('vips_vc.site_trip', 'url_prevouse_ids', string='Prevouse URL')
    site_trip_current_id =  fields.One2many('vips_vc.site_trip', 'url_current_ids',  string='Current URL')


    remote_sites_id = fields.One2many('vips_vc.remote_sites', 'site_url_ids', string='Remote site page with URL')
    remote_sites_target_url_id = fields.One2many('vips_vc.remote_sites', 'target_url_ids', string='URL on remote site page')
```

My controller:

```
def register_trip(self, currentURLid, prevouseURLid, sessionID):
        currentURLid = int(currentURLid)
        prevouseURLid = int(prevouseURLid)
        result = None
### something
            _logger.info("CREATE -----> session_ids: %r url_prevouse_ids: %r url_current_ids: %r",
                          sessionID, prevouseURLid, currentURLid)
            result = table.create({'session_ids': sessionID, 'url_prevouse_ids': prevouseURLid,
                                   'url_current_ids': currentURLid})
### something
        return result.id
```

And error is:

```
2016-08-04 17:20:52,931 24261 INFO odoov8 openerp.addons.vips_vc.controllers: CREATE -----> session_ids: 59 url_prevouse_ids: 8 url_current_ids: 1
2016-08-04 17:20:52,938 24261 ERROR odoov8 openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 540, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 577, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 313, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 310, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 806, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 406, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/my-modules/vips_vc/controllers.py", line 194, in register_session
    self.register_trip(currentURLid, prevouseURLid, sessionID)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/my-modules/vips_vc/controllers.py", line 375, in register_trip
    'url_current_ids': currentURLid})
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4094, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 508, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4279, in _create
    result += self._columns[field].set(cr, self, id_new, field, vals[field], user, rel_context) or []
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 795, in set
    for act in values:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

As you see when I'm trying to add record in vips_vc.site_trip i receive error. And error only for currentURLid. It has integer value. prevouseURLid has integer value too. prevouseURLid and currentURLid have similar relation One2Many/Many2One.

prevouseURLid is working. currentURLid isn't.

In this line I checked all param(logger output):

```
2016-08-04 17:20:52,931 24261 INFO odoov8 openerp.addons.vips_vc.controllers: CREATE -----> session_ids: 59 url_prevouse_ids: 8 url_current_ids: 1
```

url_prevouse_ids and url_current_ids have type is integer. They have defined value. They have similar relation. And insert url_current_ids return error.
Why is it happening?

Tomorrow all worked fine !

I did not touch relation. I did not touch type of variables...

UPD: After all manipulation I have this: If i'm trying to create record with any param (sessionID, prevouseURLid, currentURLid) I receiving same error: *TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable*

Answer (score 0):

I found error.
I don't know how it working early...

```
result = table.create({'session_ids': sessionID, 'url_prevouse_ids': prevouseURLid,
                                   'url_current_ids': currentURLid})
```

Here present ID record from other tables(models). When I removed all data (module was remove and install again).
After that step by step i check all data what received variables and stored in DB. I founded that vips_vc.url_list and vips_vc.session had not data. 
after that i placed such code after create all records:

```
_logger.info(".....> Commit record ID %r", result.id)
table.env.cr.commit()
```

I have no idea why it code work early without commit().